# Atmega with Stepper motor (DRVB885 driver)

Tags: c, atmega, atmel, stepper

I'm currently working at a project for school with three stepper motors, for this I'm using a nema17 stepper motor and a DRVB885 stepper motor driver. The driver is controlled by an arduino mega 2560. I want to control three things, the steps from the motor (number of PWM pulses), the speed of the motor (PWM period time) and the direction of the motor. I wrote a program to do these three things, unfortunatly my program doenst work. I get no errors or warnings (like most of the time in c) and its very hard to rotate the shaft of the stepper motor when the program is running. the motor doenst make any noise, this pushes me in to direction that the motor is being directed but duration of the pulses or setup is wrong. anyone an idea?

this is the code that I wrote:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000ul 

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "basic_help.h"

#define motor_a 1
#define dir_a_pin 1 //A1 - F
#define step_a_pin 3 //6 - H


void motor_setup() {
    
    pinmodeOutput(step_a_pin, &DDRH);
    pinmodeOutput(dir_a_pin, &DDRF);
    
    digitalWrite(en_a_pin,1,&DDRD); // disable motor
    digitalWrite(dir_a_pin,0,&DDRF); // set initial motor direction
    
    TCCR3A = 0;
    TCCR3B = 0;
    TCCR3A = (1<<COM3A1) | (1<<COM3B1) | (1<<WGM31) | (1<<WGM30); //clear timer on compare match & set timer at bottom - set pwm to fast pwm - 
    TCCR3B = (1<<CS30) | (1<<CS32) | (1<<WGM33) | (1<<WGM32);  //internal clock with CLK/1024 prescaling
    TIMSK3 = (1<<OCIE3A) | (1<<OCIE3B); //generate intterrupt when matches B register
    
};

int aantal_stappen;

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)      //PWM => COMPA  MAX, COMPB
{
    if(aantal_stappen>0)
    {
        digitalWrite(dir_a_pin,1,&DDRF); // enable direction
        digitalWrite(step_a_pin,1,&DDRH); // set pin PWM
        aantal_stappen--;
        
    }
    else if(aantal_stappen<0)
    {
        digitalWrite(dir_a_pin,0,&DDRF); // disable direction
        digitalWrite(step_a_pin,1,&DDRH); // set pin PWM
        aantal_stappen++;
    }
        
}
ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect)
{
    digitalWrite(step_a_pin,0,&DDRH); // reset pin PWM
}

int main(void)
{
    motor_setup();
    OCR0B = 156;   // clock of 16Mhz ==> prescaler 1024 ==> 15625  divided by 156 ==> 100hz 
    OCR0A = 50;     
    
    sei();
    aantal_stappen = 1000;
    
    while (1)
    {
    }
}


.c file basic_functions

void pinmodeOutput(int pin_nr, volatile uint8_t *ddr){
    *ddr |= (1<<pin_nr);
}

void digitalWrite(char pin_nr, int highLow, volatile uint8_t *port){
    if(highLow) {
        *port |= (1<<pin_nr);
        } else {
        *port &= ~(1<<pin_nr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, I would like to ask:

> Do you know if the hardware you are working with, is designed to work together?

I did a quick search for the datasheets, and the DRV8825 stepper motor driver is designed for Bipolar stepper motors. I don't think the nema17 is a bipolar stepper motor; but then again, my stepper motor knowledge is lacking.

Secondly, the DRV8825 driver only has 2 outputs (A & B). But your stepper motor requires 6 inputs.

**I would highly recommend you look back over your hardware design and then double check your question here.**

If I where you, I would look at dropping that driver module and trying to control the stepper in a more direct manner (meaning dont use pwm).

Comment: thanks for you reply! I think the stepper motor you have in mind is a diffrent one than mine, the nema stepper motor has just 4 wires as the most simple stepper motors. 4 wires with ground, 12v, a and b channel. I think the hardware is ok, it runs fine if I run it in arduino. unfortunatly in atmel with timers it just doent run so think the setup is not correct